# Change file (editor) encoding in jgrasp to UTF-8

Tags: utf-8, jgrasp, file-encodings

So... I was testing jGrasp and when i openned my testing file I saw something like this:

[Â¿KhÃ ?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i2qv9.png)

instead of this:

[¿Khà?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zzrbZ.png)

but when i compile it, first i got the weird characters (the encoding was wrong). So i changed the encoding on the WorkSpace>Charset (the default, I/O and cygwin) to UTF-8 and got the correct output (like in the second image)... but it still looks the same on jGrasp.

If I change it on jGrasp so it looks "good", on other  text editors will look diferent (and also in the compiler).

#### EDIT

I have found a few other encodings that work, but they aren't UTF-8, and also i don 't want to be changing every moment the encoding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not clear on exactly what the problem is, but if you need to open and/or edit a single file with a specific encoding different from the default, use "File" > "Open" and specify the charset on the dialog. The charset choice will be remembered.

Comment: It work , even though my error was in the encoding of the file, not the file editor, but this worked to make me realize that, Thanks :D